# IOneWay SOAP Parameters and Void Return

Tags: servicestack

I'm having a couple of issues with getting a correct WSDL generated for a ServiceStack SOAP+REST service.

The main issue is that when I use AddServiceReference the generated IOneWay is populated and the methods all return void. Looking at the provided SOAP examples it looks like ISyncReply should be populated (currently no operations at all) and the response type should be one of the fields in the DTO + Response object. What am I doing wrong?

- The types and operations are distributed across multiple namespaces
  but they are all referenced with a single ContractNamespace in AssemblyInfo
- The DTO + Response naming convention has been followed
- I thought it might be an issue with inherited Request/Response types, but even cutting them out completely doesn't change the situation, though apparently you can't inherit from a concrete type even from within a named namespace and have the operation parameters be generated properly
- Using explicit [DataContract]/[DataMember] annotations does not make a difference
- REST calls seem to be working as expected
- I'm using the latest ServiceStack binaries
- The WSDL does not have wsdl:output elements at all
- Applies both SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2 wsdls
- And just to complicate the situation still further the metadata produced in http://*/metadata for each operation seems to be completely accurate!!

Let me know if there is any specific further information I can provide.